# Move Workspaces Overview to Top in GNOME (like MacOS)

Tags: gnome, themes, workspaces, activities-overview, gnome-tweaks

I'm wondering if there's a way to move the Workspaces Overview (GNOME) to the top, like in MacOS. If you don't know what I mean by "workspaces overview," I'm talking about when you go into Activities Overview and you can see the workspaces/desktops on the right, like in the following screenshot:

[image]

All I want to do is to move that to the top instead of the right.
Maybe something to edit in the GNOME Theme CSS file? A GNOME Extension? Whatever working solution you have I will accept.

Thanks in advance!

- Ubuntu 20.04
- GNOME Version: 3.36.8

Comment: Are you talking about the Workspace overview look of GNOME 40?

Comment: @Someone I am not using GNOME 40 and I don't know anything about how GNOME 40 looks. I am using Ubuntu 20.04, GNOME Version 3.36.8 and I want to put the workspaces overview at the top, similar to MacOS.

Comment: Install Ubuntu 21.10 and workspaces will appear horizontally across the top, as you desire.

Comment: @heynnema But what if I want to stay on 20.04 LTS? Is there literally no way to accomplish what I'm trying to do on 20.04?

Comment: You can try looking for a gnome-shell extension that might do that at https://extensions.gnome.org/

Comment: @heynnema Thanks. I tried that, but there's never an end to looking for things like that. I'll keep looking. I'll still keep waiting to see if anyone has found a solution to my problem or has found an extension. Thanks

Comment: Your desire is only for appearance's sake. I wouldn't worry too much about it. You can always upgrade Ubuntu, Gnome 4.x, or use a Mac if you must have that look :-)